# Traffic control: marking packets for shaping

Tags: iptables, traffic-shaping, tc

I'm seeking advice about which technology to use to classify packets for shaping in traffic control (tc). I've found at least 3 that could be used:

- iptables MARK
- iptables CLASSIFY
- tc filter

Which one should I use? Is there one that is better than others?

Answer (score 1):

All of those are OK to do the marking but I recommend "tc filter" because:

- You have the rules in one place.
- By using hashes, you can obtain a very fast classification.